# Intersection of ideals of $R$ and $eRe$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $e=e^2\in R$ such that $ReR=R$. If $\frak {B}$ and $\frak{C}$ are ring direct summands of the ring $eRe$ with $eRe=\frak{B}\oplus \frak{C}$, then necessarily $\frak{B}\cap \frak{C}=0$, because of the direct sum between them. Is it true that $R\mathfrak{B} R\cap R \mathfrak{C}R=0$?

I know that any ring direct summand is generated by a central idempotent, and via Theorem 21.11(2) of "A First Course in Noncommutative Rings", 2nd edition (2001), by T. Y. Lam, we have $e(R\mathfrak {A}R)e=\mathfrak{A}$, for any ideal $\frak{A}$ of $eRe$, and also, the map $\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow R\mathfrak{A}R$ defines a 1-1 correspondence between the idals of $eRe$ and those of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're saying that $A\mapsto RAR$ is a bijection, namely that $I\mapsto eIe$ and $A\mapsto RAR$ are mutually inverse.

Then $e(RBR\cap RCR)e=eRBRe\cap eRCRe=B\cap C=\{0\}\lhd eRe$ implies that applying the second map to both sides will yield $RBR\cap RCR=\{0\}\lhd R$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, we would infer that $$R=R(eRe)R=R(\mathfrak{B}\oplus \mathfrak{C})R=R\mathfrak{B}R\oplus R\mathfrak{C}R,$$ since the "sum" is straightforward, and the "direct sum" arises from this question.